# SQL query to return a set of calculated values per site from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written the below and am seeking any way that I could improve its performance.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PLUTotals') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[#PLUTotals];
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Level4Totals') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[#Level4Totals];
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#WasteTotals') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[#WasteTotals];
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#GPTotal') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[#GPTotal];
SELECT SiteNo
      ,CASE
           WHEN Media = 1003
           THEN isNull(Value,0)
           ELSE 0
       END AS GrossSalesValue
      ,CASE
           WHEN Media = 1001
           THEN isNull(Qty,0)
           ELSE 0
       END AS CustomerCount
      ,CASE
           WHEN Media = 5001
                AND MediaIndex IN(1,8)
           THEN isNull(Value,0)
           ELSE 0
       END AS EodDiscount
      ,CASE
           WHEN Media = 5006
           THEN isNull(Value,0)
           ELSE 0
       END AS TotalDiscount
      ,CASE
           WHEN Media = 5001
                AND MediaIndex IN(26,168,35,38,72,193,119,208,211,212,213,47)
           THEN isNull(Qty,0)
           ELSE 0
       END AS MealDeal
INTO #PLUTotals
FROM TransactionDetail
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT Descendant
    FROM DescendantSites
    WHERE Parent IN(@SiteNo)
    AND Descendant = TransactionDetail.SiteNo
)
AND Date BETWEEN @SessionDateFrom AND @SessionDateTo
AND TermNo &gt; 0
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT MediaNo
    FROM Media
    WHERE MediaNo IN(1001,1003,5001,5006)
    AND MediaNo = TransactionDetail.Media
);
SELECT SiteNo
      ,isNull(SUM(Value),0) AS Level4Sales
INTO #Level4Totals
FROM PLUSalesExtended
WHERE [Level] + 1 = 4
      AND SessionDate BETWEEN @SessionDateFrom AND @SessionDateTo
      AND TermNo = 0
      AND PluEntryType &lt;&gt; 4
      AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT Descendant
    FROM DescendantSites
    WHERE Parent IN(@SiteNo)
    AND Descendant = PluSalesExtended.SiteNo
)
GROUP BY SiteNo;
SELECT CustomerCode AS SiteNo
      ,ABS(SUM(Waste_StandardCost)) AS WasteTotals
INTO #WasteTotals
FROM [CybakeRS].[dbo].utf_Waste(@SessionDateFrom,@SessionDateTo,1)
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT Descendant
    FROM DescendantSites
    WHERE Parent IN(@SiteNo)
    AND Descendant = CybakeRS.dbo.utf_Waste.CustomerCode
)
AND Waste_Qty &lt;&gt; 0
GROUP BY CustomerCode;
SELECT PluSales.SiteNo
      ,SUM(PluSales.Value) AS SalesValue
      ,SUM(PluSales.VatValue) AS VatAmount
      ,SUM(PluSales.Cost) AS CostOfSales
INTO #GPTotal
FROM PluSales
     INNER JOIN Sessions ON sessions.siteno = plusales.siteno
                            AND sessions.sessionno = plusales.sessionno
                            AND sessions.termno = plusales.termno
                            AND sessions.type = 7
                            AND sessions.termno = 0
WHERE sessions.sessiondate BETWEEN @SessionDateFrom AND @SessionDateTo
      AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT Descendant
    FROM DescendantSites
    WHERE Parent IN(@SiteNo)
    AND Descendant = PluSales.SiteNo
)
GROUP BY PluSales.SiteNo;
SELECT CASE
           WHEN PT.SiteNo IN(70,71)
           THEN 69
           WHEN PT.SiteNo IN(40,41)
           THEN 45
           ELSE PT.SiteNo
       END AS SiteNo
      ,SUM(PT.GrossSalesValue) AS GrossSalesValue
      ,SUM(PT.CustomerCount) AS CustomerCount
      ,SUM(PT.EodDiscount) AS EodDiscount
      ,SUM(PT.TotalDiscount) AS TotalDiscount
      ,SUM(PT.MealDeal) AS MealDeal
      ,L4T.Level4Sales AS Level4Sales
      ,WT.WasteTotals AS WasteTotals
      ,SUM(PT.MealDeal) / SUM(PT.CustomerCount) AS MealDealPercent
      ,L4T.Level4Sales / (L4T.Level4Sales + SUM(PT.EodDiscount)) AS Conversion
      ,SUM(PT.GrossSalesValue) / SUM(PT.CustomerCount) AS AveSpend
     ,SUM(GPT.SalesValue) AS GPTSales
     ,SUM(GPT.CostOfSales) AS GPTCosts
     ,SUM(GPT.VatAmount) AS GPTVatAmount
FROM #PLUTotals AS PT
     LEFT JOIN #Level4Totals AS L4T ON PT.SiteNo = L4T.SiteNo
     LEFT JOIN #WasteTotals AS WT ON PT.SiteNo = WT.SiteNo
     LEFT JOIN #GPTotal AS GPT ON PT.SiteNo = GPT.SiteNo
GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN PT.SiteNo IN(70,71)
             THEN 69
             WHEN PT.SiteNo IN(40,41)
             THEN 45
             ELSE PT.SiteNo
         END
        ,L4T.Level4Sales
        ,WT.WasteTotals;
DROP TABLE [dbo].[#PLUTotals];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[#Level4Totals];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[#WasteTotals];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[#GPTotal];
```

The code runs 5 queries. Query 1-4 prefetchs all the required data and stores the results into their own temp table. Query 5 then joins all the temp tables to give me the required result set. We have evidence that an index can improve the performance drastically but this cant easily be implemented in the clients solution at the moment. Any advice on how to improve this would be greatly appreciated. Are there any obvious pit falls that I am falling into?

Comment: There is one `DROP` at the top without an `IF`, a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: Aye, copy paste. Will update.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I have tried to make the title more relevant. Is this acceptable or do I need to refine it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with optimizing the queries is that you are severely hampered by the structure of the database. Because we have assigned several meanings to the column `Qty` and `Value` which requires `CASE` statement to parse out to get meaningful aggregation, this becomes problematic for performance.

The answer below is on the assumption that you cannot change the structure of the database but can create indices as needed. The answer furthermore presumes that the query is mission-critical so we are willing to do what we need to do make to run faster as possible.

1) You already have an `EXISTS` query to pre-filter the `TransactionDetails` table to only `MediaID` you care about and that's good. However, I would not be surprised if the engine end up doing a table scan anyway because there are too many logical filters. One possible choice is to do an individual subquery, so that each aggregation stand on their own, and allow the engine to build an execution plan that targets the specific `MediaId` and other specific criteria.

2) Building on #1, I would investigate whether it will be further improved by using filtered indices. Using the first `CASE` as an example, we could create a new index like so....

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TransactionDetail_Filtered1
ON dbo.TransactionDetail(SiteID, Date, Value)
WHERE TermNo > 0
  AND Media = 1003;
```

Observe that the hard-coded values such as `TermNo` and `Media` are filtered, so you can use the index more effectively with the standalone query (which can be used as a subquery):

```
SELECT 
  SiteNo,
  isNull(Value,0) AS GrossSalesValue
FROM dbo.TransactionDetail
WHERE TermID > 0
  AND Media = 1003
  AND Date BETWEEN @SessionDateFrom AND @SessionDateTo 
  AND EXISTS ( ... sites subquery ...)
```

Repeating the above for 3 other subqueries, with their own filtered index may or may not help, depends on the shape/volume of the data.

This will not help if they are of low selectivity. In which case, simply scanning the table is likely to be the fastest option because that way, you visit all rows only once as opposed to potentially revisiting when using multiple subqueries.

3) Create an indexed view

If you do not want to create 4 or more filtered indices (and you probably do not want that many anyway), then the alternative is to see if you can write an indexed view instead. In your initial query, you read only the TransactionDetail with some criteria. The one that are dynamic are the `SiteNo` and `Date`, so the view would need to look something similar to this....

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwTransactionDetail_Indexed 
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT SiteNo
      ,Date
      ,CASE
           WHEN Media = 1003
           THEN isNull(Value,0)
           ELSE 0
       END AS GrossSalesValue
      ,CASE
           WHEN Media = 1001
           THEN isNull(Qty,0)
           ELSE 0
       END AS CustomerCount
      ,CASE
           WHEN Media = 5001
                AND MediaIndex IN(1,8)
           THEN isNull(Value,0)
           ELSE 0
       END AS EodDiscount
      ,CASE
           WHEN Media = 5006
           THEN isNull(Value,0)
           ELSE 0
       END AS TotalDiscount
      ,CASE
           WHEN Media = 5001
                AND MediaIndex IN(26,168,35,38,72,193,119,208,211,212,213,47)
           THEN isNull(Qty,0)
           ELSE 0
       END AS MealDeal
FROM TransactionDetail
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT Descendant
    FROM DescendantSites
    WHERE Descendant = TransactionDetail.SiteNo
)
AND TermNo > 0
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT MediaNo
    FROM Media
    WHERE MediaNo IN(1001,1003,5001,5006)
    AND MediaNo = TransactionDetail.Media
);
```

That way, you can just filter the indexed view for the `SiteNo` and `Date` and use the result to insert into `#PLUTotals`. Note that I'm not 100% sure if the `EXISTS` is needed for the `DescendantSites` -- if it's a subset of all possible sites, then we'll keep that. But if it's all possible sites, then it buys us nothing so it should go, too.

4) Maintain a summary table instead

The other option which requires you to create a new table and then attach a trigger to the source tables would be to use a trigger to update the summary table and have your queries read off the summary table instead. This makes it easy to set up without adding more indices. This means instead of taking performance hit at read time, you take a bit less of a hit at write time.

Note that attaching a trigger to table is a big maintenance problem, however. I'd much prefer that it be attached to a view instead, making it opt-in, so that developers can use it when they actually need it, and skip it without having to disable it (which is a schema modification) when they do a bulk import of clean data (as an example).

**Conclusion**

The similar principles can be applied to the other queries. Put together, it should make the final query much quicker as I believe the majority of performance is tied up in the setup. You already mentioned you can't create an index at client's site. In that case, you're pretty much out of luck because as I said, database performance is strongly tied to the design of the database and frankly, it's awful that you have to do CASE WHEN with several criteria to get one answer. I realize that changing the database design is much less trivial to do, which is why I talk about indices since those don't change the physical structure of the database. I'd be talking to the client to find a way to make that happen at least.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. There are some techniques  I hadn't considered raised which is good food for thought.